# Creating pointer to Vector of boost::thread pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, boost-thread

I am attempting to make a vector of pointers to boost thread objects.  This vector then is a member of a class that is created on the heap from a pointer when the class constructor is called.  It looks something like this.

```
#ifndef NETWORKSYSTEM_H
#define NETWORKSYSTEM_H
#include "Network.h"
#include "Misc.h"
#include "Enumerators.h"
#include < vector>
#include < boost\thread.hpp>
#include < boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include < string>
#include < iostream>
class NetworkSystem
{
private:
    Status NetworkStatus;
    boost::filesystem3::path *ProjectPath;
    std::string ProjectName;
    //vector for pointers to networks
    std::vector< Network*> *M_Network;
    //Threading Components
    boost::thread *MainThread;
    std::vector< boost::thread *> *WorkerThreads;
    void MainThreadFunction();
    void WorkerThreadFunction();
public:
    NetworkSystem();
    ~NetworkSystem();
    int SetWorkerThreads(int P_WorkerThreads, bool Wait);
    int TotalNetworks();
    int WorkerThreads();
    int PauseAtNetworksCompletion(bool Wait);
    int PauseAtGenerationsCompletion(bool Wait);
};
#endif
```

```
// class constructor
NetworkSystem::NetworkSystem()
{
    ProjectPath = new boost::filesystem3::path();
    M_Network = new std::vector< Network*>;
    WorkerThreads = new std::vector< boost::thread*>;
    NetworkStatus = NO_PROJECT_OPEN;
    MainThread = new boost::thread(&NetworkSystem::MainThreadFunction, this);
};
```

Visual C++ 2010 gives me errors with the boost::thread pointer vector.  It underlines WorkerThreads in the constructor and says that "expression must be a modifiable lvalue".  I have no problems when doing the same thing with the M_Network vector.  If you believe this approach to organizing my worker threads into a vector of pointers so I can initialize and manage them individually is bad, then I suppose I COULD use a thread group, but would like to get this method to work.
Any help? Thanks.

Comment: "looks something like this" is not sufficient to say what you're doing wrong. post complete code.

Comment: Do you want me to post my entire class? (50 lines)

Comment: @JAKE6459: the best would be a minimal (but complete) version that still exhibits the problem, but 50 lines is OK.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: I added the class (took out a lot of comments to make it shorter).

Comment: @Jake why allocate `std::vector` on the heap? Internally it will allocate its storage on the heap anyhow.

Comment: @Sam Miller: If I was to not store it on the heap, would I still have to initialize it in my class constructor like "NetworkSystem(): WorkerThread(){};" or is that only if it has parameters that needs to passed to the vectors constructor?

Comment: @Jake you should always initialize class members, it just seems odd to allocate a `std::vector` on the heap when internally it will use the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar error as yours:

```
class A
{
    int B;
public:
    A()
    {
        B = 0;
    }

    int B();
};
```

Advice:  Don't name your member functions the same name as your member data.

Comment: Is using the phrase "Face-Palm" appropriate for this situation?  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem into a smaller example for others. It seems to compile for me using gcc 4.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        WorkerThreads = new std::vector<boost::thread*>;
    }

private:
    std::vector< boost::thread *> *WorkerThreads;
};

int
main()
{
    const Foo foo;
}
```

compile & link

```
g++ -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib -lboost_thread-mt vector.cc
```